# c# unwanted DrawString letter spacing

Tags: c#, winforms

I got some text from TextBox component for example `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`. After that I hide this TextBox and draw text with DrawString on same place with same OpenSans font. But I'll get something like this. `"aaaaaaaaaaaa  a  a  a  a  a  a"`. Spaces are smaller but still visible and first part of string is good.  I want to hide this difference between textbox and DrawString. Where is the problem? Why do these spaces appear?

```
    PointF point = new PointF(
(this.shift.x + cx + rec.position.x + padding) / s, 
(this.shift.y + cy + rec.position.y + padding) / s
);

gfx.DrawString(rec.text, new Font(rec.font.FontFamily, rec.font.Size / s, rec.font.Style), new SolidBrush(rec.fontcolor), point);
```

Example application. First is textbox then label and last is DrawString.

[example application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye4tY.jpg)

Comment: please show the code you are using for DrawString, i.e. value of parameters you are using

Comment: Is this Web? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: `new Font(...)` and `new SolidBrush(...)` are disposable, and should not be anonymously created like that. Better: `using (var f = new Font(...)) using (var b = new SolidBrush(...)) { ... }`

Comment: We need more of the code, esp. how the code is called!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a `Label` control instead of drawing text. It handles the drawing for you and gives a lot more control in an easier way.

Even though many labels may seem ugly, drawing can become very complicated, as you can see, and requires a highly disciplined OO approach to write bug free components such as a Diagram Control without introducing several hard to fix bugs. Either approach is viable, but drawing will surely be harder and may take longer. If disabled labels don't interfere with the appearance or usage, they will be easier to manage.

When you hide the `TextBox`, you can show the `Label`.

If you must draw strings, be sure to clear the area before you draw them. The extra a's you see are probably remnants of previous draws that were not erased. Graphics.Clear(color) is the method you use to clear the entire form or control, or Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, Color) if you need to clear just an area.

Comment: This DrawString is part of diagram program. It can have lot of strings in one form.

Comment: Well, you can draw strings, it's just more challenging. Did clearing the background first solve it?